# Meteor app will not run due to a release error

Tags: meteor

Whenever I try to run meteor I get the following error, not sure what is causing it, I did move some files around in a meteor project, replaced old files with new files manually, not sure if that caused the problem:

Problem! This project does not have a .meteor/release file. The file should either
contain the release of Meteor that you want to use, or the word 'none' if you will only
use the project with unreleased checkouts of Meteor. Please edit the .meteor/release
file in the project and change it to a valid Meteor release or 'none'

Comment: Please copy paste the contents of your .meteor/release file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're missing the release file. My .meteor/release file contains the following:

```
METEOR@1.2.1
```

Try adding the version you are running to this file (yours may not be 1.2.1).